# How to build with travis-ci, with no actual code build? (deploy static code to s3)

Tags: amazon-s3, travis-ci

I'm using the directions provided [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/s3/) to try and deploy static code from a github push to an s3 bucket.  The problem is on a build I get the following errors:

```
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The command "rake" exited with 1.
```

It seems since I don't have a language set that I am defaulting to ruby and it is trying to build with a makefile.  Thing is: I don't have any code to build.  I don't need to do anything in any language. Just upload the code to S3.  So is there a way to not run an actual build and have this work?

My .travis.yml looks like:

```
deploy:
  provider: s3
  access_key_id: myaccesskey
  secret_access_key:
    secure: myverylongsecurysecretkey
  bucket: searchlist.org
  acl: public_read
  on:
    repo: myuser/myrepo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For historical reasons, Travis CI assumes your build is a Ruby app/lib. If your repo requires something else, you need to override these defaults.

Either

```
language: generic # no-frills build
⋮
```

or

```
# Ruby, but override default steps
install: skip
script: skip
⋮
```